# Can I share my local printers redirected by RDP with other computers on the local network? Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, printer, network-shares

I am using my W7 through RDP and I have a local printer redirected to the RDP server.
But I have found out that I can't share my local redirected printer with other network computers (my colleagues) we work in the room and they used to print through my PC.

Now, when I got to. **Printer Properties** -> **Sharing**

That page is all greyed.

I have tried to log in to the machine as Domain Admin and Local Admin (the first user)

Comment: *I can't share my local redirected printer with other network users* You mean on the server? I would expect because it's a *temporary* mapping.

Comment: @todda.speot.is thanks for pointing out! No, I mean other computers not users on the same computer

Comment: You're using W7 via RDP? Perhaps try the same operation on the original computer, without logging in via RDP? There might be some restrictions that result from accessing the computer via RDP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can't. Because those redirected printers are connected with the remote desktop and the client only. There is no access from other machines.

Those printers called Transient printers and they are temporarily created

Answer (score -1):

Try logging in with a user account that has Administrator privileges. You can check your privileges in the "Control Panel" and "User Accounts" section.

Comment: you need to stop posting multiple answers.  Use the `edit` button to revise or update your answer. you also have enough rep to comment.